# finding length of linked list in constant time python

Tags: python, list, linked-list, time-complexity

I'm trying to write a function which finds the length of a linked list in O(1).
I know how to implement it in O(n) but I can't figure out how to do it in constant time... is that even possible?

Comment: It is only possible when you keep it in a separate class attribute.

Comment: It's possible if the linked list datastructure keeps its length as an attribute. Otherwise - not.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible because you have to atleast pass through entire linked list and it takes O(n)

Else you have to use a variable which counts when inserting elements into linked list